# How to arrange two divs abutting one another?

Tags: css, html

So, the issue is rather obvious. Now I've two elements in div containers, that should abut one another, but because of lack of css skills I need your help. So, the code is rather primitive.

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title>Новый формат общения</title>
    <html>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="center_ribbon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="center.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <style>


 .center {
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%; 
    width: 310px; 
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute; 
    margin-top: -155px; 
    margin-left: -25px; 
}

    </style>
    <body>
      <div class="center"><div class="ribbon"><div class="ribbon-stitches-top"></div><strong class="ribbon-content"><h1>foo</h1></strong><div class="ribbon-stitches-bottom"></div></div></div>

      <div class="wrap"><div class = "lifted">
        <p>footext</p></div></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

So, the corresponding code of css as follows

center_ribbon.css

```
html, body {height:100%;}
.wrap_ribbon {

  position:relative;
  width:50%; 
  margin: 0px auto ;

  height:auto !important;
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
}
.contentdiv_ribbon {
display:block;
position:fixed;
margin-top: 200px;
margin-left: 170px;
}
```

center.css

```
html, body {height:100%;}
.wrap {
.center {
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%; 
    width: 260px; 
    height: 50px; 
    position: absolute; 
    margin-top: -25px;
    margin-left: -130px; 
}
}
```

As you can rightly notice, here is mess of code, sorry for that. I'm new to css and other web stuff and just poking around. Any improvements would be appreciated.

UPD. Added my page http://jsfiddle.net/7xZLM/5/

Comment: Use jsfiddle for such questions

Comment: 'that should abut one another' meaning ?

Comment: @TilwinJoy, meaning is that they should fit together without gaps.

Comment: Please explain your question in detail. Vertically fit together/horizontally?

Comment: @im_infamous any particular reason for not doing it as simple as this? http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/N7d5G/1/ why all the empty divs and css spam..?

Comment: @TilwinJoy, sorry for that. Here is complete code. http://jsfiddle.net/7xZLM/5/

Comment: Where exactly do you want it to be? Your question is unclear.

Comment: @bjb568, as you can see in feedle, these two divs are splitted. I want them to look like one element.

Comment: So .lifted right below .center? Or on the right? On the left? Above? Over?

Comment: Wondering whether the answer helped

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<head>
<style>
.main {
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
<div class="column">DIV 1</div>
<div class="column">DIV 2</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Click [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HuMzZ/)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what you're asking. It sounds like you want 2 `divs` that sit next to each other. If so, you're wanting to look at [`float`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) in CSS.

**[simplified example](http://jsfiddle.net/N7d5G/4/)**

CSS

```
.col1 {
    float: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='bold col1'> foo</div>
<div class='col2'>footext</div>
```

Comment: As far as i can see there is a comment option for clarifications right below the question...

Comment: @TJ, oh really? when did that happen? (.)(.) jk. I'm very aware of that. And as you can see, others were confused by the same thing & the OP had not responded yet. So I took a stab at solving his problem. He indicated that he was new to CSS, and `float` isn't something that a lot of people pick up instinctively.

Answer (score 0):

An absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to the first parent having position other than static, if none is there it'll be positioned relative to the initial container, `<html>`

In your code `.wrap` doesn't have a positioned parent so it'll be positioned relative to the document, top:50%` will position the div 50% below the top of document...

**Update**
Since `.wrap` is positioned relative to the document, it's position changes with the height of the page, while the ribbon will stay at the top of the page, causing space between them.
Wrapping them inside a positioned parent will fix the issue.

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/7xZLM/9/)

And from what i understood, you need the .wrap to look like it's coming out from the ribbon, for that you can apply an `z-index` less than the ribbon to `.wrap`,

as in this [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/7xZLM/10/)

Comment: thank you for reply. But is there way to put two this divs so that it will be look like one element without gaps? I understand, that this ribbon is smaller, but that's not the point.